# Can't get swapExactTokensForTokens on pancakeswap to work

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, contract, bsc

I'm struggling with getting swapExactTokensForTokens to work on pancakeswap I just cannot see why it keeps failing I call giveAllowances() and send 0.1 cake to the contract then call sellCake() - both egg and cake has liquidity with wbnb so I really don't understand what the issue is.

See the partial code below

```
    address public egg = 0xF952Fc3ca7325Cc27D15885d37117676d25BfdA6;
    address public cake = 0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82;
    address public router = 0xF491e7B69E4244ad4002BC14e878a34207E38c29;
    address public dead = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
    address public wbnb = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c;
    address[] public route = [cake, wbnb, egg];


    function giveAllowances() external onlyOwner {
        IBEP20(cake).safeApprove(router, uint256(-1));
    }


    function sellCake() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 _bal = IBEP20(cake).balanceOf(address(this));

        if (_bal > 0) {
            IUniswapV2Router02(router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_bal, 0, route, dead, now);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error information? If so please add it to the question. Moreover the value of now is interesting, because documentation claims that his value indicates when transaction will be reverted, so if you have now from the past there is not time to execute requestes transaction.

Comment: What is the `now` in your code?! Is it `block.timestamp`?!

Comment: hi all thanks for your replies but it was completely my fault i completely missed that i had the incorrect router address and was trying to fix some thing that wasn't broken! : )